# jquery how do i reach element id when element is stored in variable

Tags: jquery, selector

is it possible to get element id when element is stored in variable?

```
var element = $("#someElement")
var id = element.id();
```

if i have something like that its not working. Element is also only stored in variable, not in DOM right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` is a property of the element `#someElement`, not a method of the jQuery collection `$("#someElement")`.

Therefore

```
var id = element.prop('id');
```

or

```
var id = element.get(0).id;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
var id = element.attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) or [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop):

```
var id = element.attr("id"); // or .prop("id")
```

or if you know that there's exactly one element in the jQuery object, you can do it by going directly to the element, since DOM elements expose their `id` via the `id` reflected property:

```
var id = element[0].id;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of doing it would be :

```
varName.attr('id');
```

Comment: Well, one of three or four correct ways, anyhow. :-)